# Authlogic: how to know last time a user came to my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I'd like to know last time a logged-in user accessed my site.

I'm using Authlogic and I already have a "current_login_at" column in my user database, but if a user is using the "remember me" checkbox in the login page the "current_login_at" column is not updated when he is using an old (but still valid) session.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Augusto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another one column `last_request_at` and Authlogic will update it automatically.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly!  I love Rails and I love Stackoverflow! :)